# Lost all changes after source tree soft reset

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Lost all changes after source tree soft reset. How to get back local changes?

I have tried following command:

```
git --hard reset sha-1
```

of lost commit, but no affect.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Ivan. `git reset--soft` does *not* modify your working tree. There must have been something else going on before or after, could you give the entire series of commands you tried?

Comment: `git reset --hard` would get rid of your changes, `git reset --soft` does not.

Comment: If changes were committed, you could find them by doing `git reflog` and try to look for the commit in which they were included, and then checkout/cherry-pick/reset to that commit, depending on what you want. If changes were never committed, they may have been lost as a result of the `git reset --hard` command.

Comment: Make proper description of question.